# Windows 10 keeps navigating upwards on the Start Menu and on the settings menu, but not in other apps

Tags: windows, start-menu, scrolling, input

I have an unusual problem on my Windows 10 device. When I try to use the Start Menu or the Settings menu, the system behaves as if I'm constantly holding the up arrow key.

Here's a video of this behavior. In this video I open the Start Menu and scroll downwards rapidly. The menu keeps jumping back to the top. I practically can't run any applications whose name starts with a letter beyond "A".

[image]

Here are some relevant facts:

- This does not affect all applications. It only seems to affect certain Windows apps, including the Xbox game overlay. My Web browser works fine, for instance.
- Rebooting did not resolve the issue.
- The Scroll Lock key is off.
- The issue occurs even if I unplug my mouse, keyboard, and gamepad.
- I did not recently update my system configuration.
- This issue started happening today, a few hours before I wrote this post.

Specifics of my Windows edition are as follows:

```
Edition         Windows 10 Pro
Version         21H2
Installed on    ‎12/‎24/‎2021
OS build        19044.1645
Experience      Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0
```

## New Info

I didn't make the connection before yesterday, but this mostly happens when I finish playing video games with one of my Xbox One controllers. The controller is connected via an Xbox-branded USB cable, as opposed to Bluetooth. The issue persists even after I unplug the controller.

Comment: Perhaps see if DISM and SFC (Windows Initial Repairs).  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: @John Sure, I'll try that, but in the meantime: What does that do, and why is it relevant?

Comment: Initial repairs as I outlined can fix numerous Windows issues. That is why I suggest it as a starting point,

Comment: @John That *did* make the issue go away, so thanks! However, I'm not prepared to call this problem resolved yet. I want to see if it comes back first. It's always something...but if you post your suggestion as a full answer, I'll accept it once the issue doesn't recur for a few days.

Comment: I posted an answer for you as you asked.

Comment: Create a new user on your machine and log into it for the first time. Does the issue occur in the new user? If no, then backup all your user files (desktop, documents, pictures etc..), delete your user profile and re-create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Windows 10 keeps navigating upwards on the Start Menu and on the
> settings menu, but not in other apps

What I do in this situation is to run the Initial Windows Repair sequence. (DISM and SFC).  This will solve some, but not all issues, and is worth running and evaluating.

(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup

(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth

(4) SFC /SCANNOW

(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: I just noticed that the issue I originally described seems to happen most frequently after I disconnect an Xbox One controller that I frequently use. I can't help but think that knowledge could lead to a solution that *doesn't* involve rebooting every time I finish playing video games?

Comment: You should not have to reboot when finishing a game. Try reinstalling the Xbox controller. It may be in Settings, Apps. Also try a different user account to see if user account is the issue.