# WSL fails to start in Windows 10: "The specified module could not be found." (Error 0x8007007e)

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm trying to run WSL in Windows 10. However, doing so returns a vague `The specified module could not be found` error. I initially thought it was a problem with Docker, until I tried to run WSL independently of it.

I uninstalled all traces of my WSL instances (and of Docker, too), then attempted to reinstall them from the Windows store. Running the `ubuntu` command yields the following output:

```
PS C:\Users\Jesse> ubuntu
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x8007007e
Error: 0x8007007e The specified module could not be found.

Press any key to continue...
```

`wsl --status` displays the following output:

```
PS C:\Users\Jesse> wsl --status
Default Version: 2

Windows Subsystem for Linux was last updated on 3/29/2022
WSL automatic updates are on.

Kernel version: 5.10.102.1
```

And this is my edition of Windows:

```
Edition          Windows 10 Pro
Version          21H2
Installed on     ‎12/‎24/‎2021
OS build         19044.1645
Experience       Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0
```

Here is the output of `bcdedit /v`. I don't know if it's actually related, but another Super User question about WSL difficulties included it.

```
PS C:\Users\Jesse> bcdedit /v

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {65875d57-62bf-11ec-bef5-a8a1599b691e}
resumeobject            {65875d56-62bf-11ec-bef5-a8a1599b691e}
displayorder            {65875d57-62bf-11ec-bef5-a8a1599b691e}
                        {65875d5a-62bf-11ec-bef5-a8a1599b691e}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 1
displaybootmenu         No
customactions           0x1000044000001
                        0x54000001
custom:54000001         {65875d5a-62bf-11ec-bef5-a8a1599b691e}

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {65875d57-62bf-11ec-bef5-a8a1599b691e}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {65875d58-62bf-11ec-bef5-a8a1599b691e}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \windows
resumeobject            {65875d56-62bf-11ec-bef5-a8a1599b691e}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Legacy
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {65875d5a-62bf-11ec-bef5-a8a1599b691e}
device                  ramdisk=[R:]\sources\recoveryboot.wim,{65875d5b-62bf-11ec-bef5-a8a1599b691e}
path                    \WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\BOOT\WINLOAD.efi
description             LT_Recovery
locale                  EN_US
osdevice                ramdisk=[R:]\sources\recoveryboot.wim,{65875d5b-62bf-11ec-bef5-a8a1599b691e}
systemroot              \WINDOWS
detecthal               Yes
winpe                   Yes
```

Here's the output of `coreinfo64`:

```
Coreinfo v3.52 - Dump information on system CPU and memory topology
Copyright (C) 2008-2021 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2950X 16-Core Processor
AMD64 Family 23 Model 8 Stepping 2, AuthenticAMD
Microcode signature: 00000000
HTT             *       Multicore
CET             -       Supports Control Flow Enforcement Technology
Kernel CET      -       Kernel-mode CET Enabled
User CET        -       User-mode CET Allowed
HYPERVISOR      *       Hypervisor is present
VMX             -       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
SVM             -       Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization
X64             *       Supports 64-bit mode

SMX             -       Supports Intel trusted execution
SKINIT          -       Supports AMD SKINIT
SGX             -       Supports Intel SGX

NX              *       Supports no-execute page protection
SMEP            *       Supports Supervisor Mode Execution Prevention
SMAP            *       Supports Supervisor Mode Access Prevention
PAGE1GB         *       Supports 1 GB large pages
PAE             *       Supports > 32-bit physical addresses
PAT             *       Supports Page Attribute Table
PSE             *       Supports 4 MB pages
PSE36           *       Supports > 32-bit address 4 MB pages
PGE             *       Supports global bit in page tables
SS              -       Supports bus snooping for cache operations
VME             *       Supports Virtual-8086 mode
RDWRFSGSBASE    *       Supports direct GS/FS base access

FPU             *       Implements i387 floating point instructions
MMX             *       Supports MMX instruction set
MMXEXT          *       Implements AMD MMX extensions
3DNOW           -       Supports 3DNow! instructions
3DNOWEXT        -       Supports 3DNow! extension instructions
SSE             *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions
SSE2            *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 2
SSE3            *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 3
SSSE3           *       Supports Supplemental SIMD Extensions 3
SSE4a           *       Supports Streaming SIMDR Extensions 4a
SSE4.1          *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.1
SSE4.2          *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2

AES             *       Supports AES extensions
AVX             *       Supports AVX instruction extensions
AVX2            *       Supports AVX2 instruction extensions
AVX-512-F       -       Supports AVX-512 Foundation instructions
AVX-512-DQ      -       Supports AVX-512 double and quadword instructions
AVX-512-IFAMA   -       Supports AVX-512 integer Fused multiply-add instructions
AVX-512-PF      -       Supports AVX-512 prefetch instructions
AVX-512-ER      -       Supports AVX-512 exponential and reciprocal instructions
AVX-512-CD      -       Supports AVX-512 conflict detection instructions
AVX-512-BW      -       Supports AVX-512 byte and word instructions
AVX-512-VL      -       Supports AVX-512 vector length instructions
FMA             *       Supports FMA extensions using YMM state
MSR             *       Implements RDMSR/WRMSR instructions
MTRR            *       Supports Memory Type Range Registers
XSAVE           *       Supports XSAVE/XRSTOR instructions
OSXSAVE         *       Supports XSETBV/XGETBV instructions
RDRAND          *       Supports RDRAND instruction
RDSEED          *       Supports RDSEED instruction

CMOV            *       Supports CMOVcc instruction
CLFSH           *       Supports CLFLUSH instruction
CX8             *       Supports compare and exchange 8-byte instructions
CX16            *       Supports CMPXCHG16B instruction
BMI1            *       Supports bit manipulation extensions 1
BMI2            *       Supports bit manipulation extensions 2
ADX             *       Supports ADCX/ADOX instructions
DCA             -       Supports prefetch from memory-mapped device
F16C            *       Supports half-precision instruction
FXSR            *       Supports FXSAVE/FXSTOR instructions
FFXSR           *       Supports optimized FXSAVE/FSRSTOR instruction
MONITOR         -       Supports MONITOR and MWAIT instructions
MOVBE           *       Supports MOVBE instruction
ERMSB           -       Supports Enhanced REP MOVSB/STOSB
PCLMULDQ        *       Supports PCLMULDQ instruction
POPCNT          *       Supports POPCNT instruction
LZCNT           *       Supports LZCNT instruction
SEP             *       Supports fast system call instructions
LAHF-SAHF       *       Supports LAHF/SAHF instructions in 64-bit mode
HLE             -       Supports Hardware Lock Elision instructions
RTM             -       Supports Restricted Transactional Memory instructions

DE              *       Supports I/O breakpoints including CR4.DE
DTES64          -       Can write history of 64-bit branch addresses
DS              -       Implements memory-resident debug buffer
DS-CPL          -       Supports Debug Store feature with CPL
PCID            -       Supports PCIDs and settable CR4.PCIDE
INVPCID         -       Supports INVPCID instruction
PDCM            -       Supports Performance Capabilities MSR
RDTSCP          *       Supports RDTSCP instruction
TSC             *       Supports RDTSC instruction
TSC-DEADLINE    -       Local APIC supports one-shot deadline timer
TSC-INVARIANT   *       TSC runs at constant rate
xTPR            -       Supports disabling task priority messages

EIST            -       Supports Enhanced Intel Speedstep
ACPI            -       Implements MSR for power management
TM              -       Implements thermal monitor circuitry
TM2             -       Implements Thermal Monitor 2 control
APIC            *       Implements software-accessible local APIC
x2APIC          -       Supports x2APIC

CNXT-ID         -       L1 data cache mode adaptive or BIOS

MCE             *       Supports Machine Check, INT18 and CR4.MCE
MCA             *       Implements Machine Check Architecture
PBE             -       Supports use of FERR#/PBE# pin

PSN             -       Implements 96-bit processor serial number

PREFETCHW       *       Supports PREFETCHW instruction

Maximum implemented CPUID leaves: 0000000D (Basic), 8000001E (Extended).
Maximum implemented address width: 48 bits (virtual), 48 bits (physical).

Processor signature: 00800F82

Logical to Physical Processor Map:
**------------------------------  Physical Processor 0 (Hyperthreaded)
--**----------------------------  Physical Processor 1 (Hyperthreaded)
----**--------------------------  Physical Processor 2 (Hyperthreaded)
------**------------------------  Physical Processor 3 (Hyperthreaded)
--------**----------------------  Physical Processor 4 (Hyperthreaded)
----------**--------------------  Physical Processor 5 (Hyperthreaded)
------------**------------------  Physical Processor 6 (Hyperthreaded)
--------------**----------------  Physical Processor 7 (Hyperthreaded)
----------------**--------------  Physical Processor 8 (Hyperthreaded)
------------------**------------  Physical Processor 9 (Hyperthreaded)
--------------------**----------  Physical Processor 10 (Hyperthreaded)
----------------------**--------  Physical Processor 11 (Hyperthreaded)
------------------------**------  Physical Processor 12 (Hyperthreaded)
--------------------------**----  Physical Processor 13 (Hyperthreaded)
----------------------------**--  Physical Processor 14 (Hyperthreaded)
------------------------------**  Physical Processor 15 (Hyperthreaded)

Logical Processor to Socket Map:
********************************  Socket 0

Logical Processor to NUMA Node Map:
********************************  NUMA Node 0
-  NUMA Node 1

Approximate Cross-NUMA Node Access Cost (relative to fastest):
     00  01
00: 1.3 1.0
01: 0.0 0.0

Logical Processor to Cache Map:
**------------------------------  Data Cache          0, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
**------------------------------  Instruction Cache   0, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
**------------------------------  Unified Cache       0, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
********------------------------  Unified Cache       1, Level 3,    8 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
--**----------------------------  Data Cache          1, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--**----------------------------  Instruction Cache   1, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
--**----------------------------  Unified Cache       2, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----**--------------------------  Data Cache          2, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----**--------------------------  Instruction Cache   2, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
----**--------------------------  Unified Cache       3, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------**------------------------  Data Cache          3, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------**------------------------  Instruction Cache   3, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
------**------------------------  Unified Cache       4, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--------**----------------------  Data Cache          4, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--------**----------------------  Instruction Cache   4, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
--------**----------------------  Unified Cache       5, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--------********----------------  Unified Cache       6, Level 3,    8 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
----------**--------------------  Data Cache          5, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----------**--------------------  Instruction Cache   5, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
----------**--------------------  Unified Cache       7, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------------**------------------  Data Cache          6, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------------**------------------  Instruction Cache   6, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
------------**------------------  Unified Cache       8, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--------------**----------------  Data Cache          7, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--------------**----------------  Instruction Cache   7, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
--------------**----------------  Unified Cache       9, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----------------**--------------  Data Cache          8, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----------------**--------------  Instruction Cache   8, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
----------------**--------------  Unified Cache      10, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----------------********--------  Unified Cache      11, Level 3,    8 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
------------------**------------  Data Cache          9, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------------------**------------  Instruction Cache   9, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
------------------**------------  Unified Cache      12, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--------------------**----------  Data Cache         10, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--------------------**----------  Instruction Cache  10, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
--------------------**----------  Unified Cache      13, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----------------------**--------  Data Cache         11, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----------------------**--------  Instruction Cache  11, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
----------------------**--------  Unified Cache      14, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------------------------**------  Data Cache         12, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------------------------**------  Instruction Cache  12, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
------------------------**------  Unified Cache      15, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------------------------********  Unified Cache      16, Level 3,    8 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
--------------------------**----  Data Cache         13, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--------------------------**----  Instruction Cache  13, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
--------------------------**----  Unified Cache      17, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----------------------------**--  Data Cache         14, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----------------------------**--  Instruction Cache  14, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
----------------------------**--  Unified Cache      18, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------------------------------**  Data Cache         15, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------------------------------**  Instruction Cache  15, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
------------------------------**  Unified Cache      19, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64

Logical Processor to Group Map:
********************************  Group 0
```

---

Here are some other related facts:

- I have previously used WSL on this machine before, without any issues. I don't know what changed.
- This [GitHub discussion (formerly an issue)](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/8359) suggests that "Registration for one of the relevant hyper-v components seems to be borked on [my] system." Specifically, `vmsmb.dll` may be part of the problem.
- I have disabled (then rebooted) and enabled (then rebooted again) the following Windows features. Doing so did not resolve the problem. I have other optional features enabled, but they're not relevant.

  - Containers
  - Hyper-V

    - Hyper-V Management Tools
    - Hyper-V Module for Windows PowerShell
  - Hyper-V Platform

    - Hyper-V Hypervisor
    - Hyper-V Services
  - Virtual Machine Platform
  - Windows Hypervisor Platform
  - Windows Subsystem for Linux
- I initially thought the problem was Docker, but I have ruled it out.
- `wsl -l -v` shows that `Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.`
- I took a trace file [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/files/8594863/wsl.etl.zip). I don't know what's in it or how to interpret it.
- Running DISM and SFC as described in this [unrelated but convenient answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1717841/windows-10-keeps-navigating-upwards-on-the-start-menu-and-on-the-settings-menu/1717845#1717845) did not resolve the problem.
- I don't have any third-party virtualization software (e.g. VirtualBox, VMWare) installed.

Any tips?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135920/discussion-on-question-by-jessetg-wsl-fails-to-start-in-windows-10-the-specifi).

Comment: I just don't want this to become another one of [_those_](https://xkcd.com/979) threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the nuclear option and reinstalled Windows using the "Reset this PC" feature in "Updates & Security" and "Recovery". I kept my personal files, but I still had to spend all day reinstalling everything. After setting up WSL again, I can now affirm that the issue is resolved.

This is the least satisfying solution possible, but it works.